# how to rescale a bezierpath

Tags: ios, scaling, uibezierpath

I have a simple image made from 3 or 4 uibezierpath lines.

when i double the size of the view in which they are drawn, they look fuzzy, like a low resolution pic displayed on a high resolution screen, stretched out. is there a way to rescale the path to fir in any size window? thanks, i know this might be a basic question, but i haven't found any information about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer. contexts can be scaled. CGContextScaleCTM. worked like a charm